# Logistic Regresion with gradient descension mini batch

Tags: python, logistic-regression, gradient-descent, mini-batch

I developed an algorithm of gradient descent, but when I try it with some sklearn exampples the results are incorrect and I do not know how to fix it.
This is the full algorithm:

First of all I have a class for an exception and a function to calculate score called rendimiento():

```
class ClasificadorNoEntrenado(Exception): pass

def rendimiento(clasificador, X, y):
aciertos = 0
total_ejemplos = len(X)

    for i in range(total_ejemplos):
        ejemplo = X[i]
        clasificacion_esperada = y[i]
        clasificacion_obtenida = clasificador.clasifica(ejemplo)
        
        if clasificacion_obtenida == clasificacion_esperada:
            aciertos += 1
    
    accuracy = aciertos / total_ejemplos
    return accuracy
```

Second, I have a function that calculates sigmoide:

```
from scipy.special import expit

def sigmoide(x):
    return expit(x)
```

Third, I have the main algorithm:

```
class RegresionLogisticaMiniBatch():

    def __init__(self,clases=[0,1],normalizacion=False,
                  rate=0.1,rate_decay=False,batch_tam=64):
    
        self.clases = clases;
        self.rate = rate;
        self.normalizacion = normalizacion;
        self.rate_decay = rate_decay;
        self.batch_tam = batch_tam;
        self.pesos = None
        self.media = None
        self.desviacion = None
    
    
    def entrena(self, X, y, n_epochs, reiniciar_pesos=False, pesos_iniciales=None):
        self.X = X
        self.y = y
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs
        
        if reiniciar_pesos or self.pesos is None:
            self.pesos = pesos_iniciales if pesos_iniciales is not None else np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=X.shape[1])
    
        if self.normalizacion:
            self.media = np.mean(X, axis=0)
            self.desviacion = np.std(X, axis=0)
    
        indices = np.random.permutation(len(X))
        X_shuffled = X[indices]
        y_shuffled = y[indices]
        for i in range(0, len(X), self.batch_tam):
            batch_X = X_shuffled[i:i + self.batch_tam]
            batch_y = y_shuffled[i:i + self.batch_tam]
        
            # Compute logistic function (sigmoid)
            z = np.dot(batch_X, self.pesos)
            y_pred = sigmoide(z)
    
            # Compute gradient
            error = batch_y - y_pred
            gradiente = np.dot(batch_X.T, error) / len(batch_X)
    
            # Update weights
            self.pesos += self.rate * gradiente
    
    def clasifica_prob(self, ejemplo):
        if self.pesos is None:
            raise ClasificadorNoEntrenado("El clasificador no ha sido entrenado")
    
        if self.normalizacion:
            ejemplo = (ejemplo - self.media) / self.desviacion
    
        probabilidad = sigmoide(np.dot(ejemplo, self.pesos))
        if probabilidad >= 0.5:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    
        
        #return {'no': 1 - probabilidad, 'si': probabilidad} 
     
    def clasifica(self,ejemplo):
        probabilidad = self.clasifica_prob(ejemplo)
        return probabilidad
```

And finally I try to see if it is correct with a dataset of sklearn:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer=load_breast_cancer()

X_cancer,y_cancer=cancer.data,cancer.target

lr_cancer=RegresionLogisticaMiniBatch(rate=0.1,rate_decay=True,normalizacion=True)

Xe_cancer, Xt_cancer, ye_cancer, yt_cancer = train_test_split(X_cancer, y_cancer);

lr_cancer.entrena(Xe_cancer,ye_cancer,10000)

print(rendimiento(lr_cancer,Xe_cancer,ye_cancer))

print(rendimiento(lr_cancer,Xt_cancer,yt_cancer))
```

But the results are very random and low.

I tried to developed a Logistic Regression with gradient descent and mini batch algorithm but it not predicts correct, hope someone could help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems that I see here.

The first problem is normalization. The `self.normalizacion` variable is used to control whether normalization is used. However, when it is set, it affects prediction, but not training.

If the weights of your model are learned on a non-normalized dataset, they will perform very poorly on a normalized dataset.

I suggest changing your code like this to normalize during training:

```
        # within entrena
        if self.normalizacion:
            self.media = np.mean(X, axis=0)
            self.desviacion = np.std(X, axis=0)
            X = (X - self.media) / self.desviacion
```

The second problem is epochs. Training epochs refers to when a model re-trains on the same dataset many times, so that randomly assigned weights move closer to their ideal values. You have an `n_epochs` variable, but it does not do anything.

Therefore, I suggest having two loops. The outer loop loops over epochs. The inner one loops over minibatches.

```
        # within entrena
        for j in range(n_epochs):
            for i in range(0, len(X), self.batch_tam):
                # same loop as before
```

With these changes I can get 99% accuracy on the training set, and 95% accuracy on the test set.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was struggling a lot to make it worked.